# Dialog doesn't "pop up" but redirects the entire page

Tags: jquery, dialog, fullcalendar

I am currently working on a calendar using the Fullcalendar jquery plugin.
I need a dialog to be opened when you click an event.
When I click an event on the calender for a split second I get the gray background you get when you open a dialog, then the dialog that is supposed to pop-up just clears the page and opens (so the calendar dissapears).
I've been looking everwhere and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code for the clickevent :

```
eventClick: function (event) {
    if (event.url) {
        var page = event.url
        var title = "test"
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 300,
                width: 600,
                title: title,
                position: "top"
            });
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    }
    return false
}
```

EDIT :

Appearantly it has something to do with the jquery version. 
These are my imports :

```
<link href='../../../Scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../../../Scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<%--<script src='../../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>--%>
<%--<script src='../../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script>--%>
<script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/dialog/jquery.dialog.min.js" type="text/javascript">       </script>
<script src='../../../Scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<link href="../../../Scripts/dialog/css/ui-lightness/jquery.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

When I use the lower version of jquery the dialog works fine. I need the new version though to implement drag & drop. 
Been looking all day for a solution but can't find one. Any help would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE:

I have now imported jquery-migrate-1.2.0.js, and the dialog shows up. But now I'm having a new issue : The events in the calendar pop up on top of the dialog, after opening the dialog a couple of times it seems to fix itself. But it's still pretty annoying, right now I'm resolving it by hiding the calendar when the dialogs opens, but i'd like to have it shown in the background...

Comment: Hmm... returning false should prevent the default redirect action. Can you debug into the function and make sure it's being called?

Comment: Probably because of the iframe. Does a static dialog open correctly?

Comment: I've been looking into the problem all day. It seems to have something to do with the jquery version.. When i use jquery-1.7.1.min.js the dialog works fine. When I use jquery-1.9.1.min.js the dialog doesn't open, and the default redirect action is called. I have to have the new jquery version though because I need to implement drag & drop.. I don't understand why it won't work though, and I'm not able to find any info about it on google.